# NativeScript does not work on Linux with Node.js 11.1.0

Tags: android, node.js, linux, npm, nativescript

I am trying to set up NativeScript on my Arch Linux machine and When I run`tns doctor`I encounter the following message

```
Support for Node.js 11.1.0 is not verified. NativeScript CLI might not install or run properly.

ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined
    at fs.js:25:1
    at req_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/natives/index.js:140:5)
    at Object.req [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/natives/index.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:99)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
```

I do not have much experience neither in Native Script nor in Node.js and related technologies. Is there any simple fix for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript CLI doesn't officially support Node v11.x.x, [try > 8 & < 11](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/blob/master/package.json#L130-L133).

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0 <11.0.0"
  }
```